# Unable to user pipeline module inside transformers library

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I have an issue. I'm using Python 3.11 and I have the latest version of transformers 4.36.2

The issue is that when I'm importing the pipeline module I facing the following issue in Jupyter Notebook:

```
RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.pipelines because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
cannot import name 'formatargspec' from 'inspect' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/inspect.py)
```

I've tried to restart the kernel, my computer, uninstall transformers, also I found that 4.28.0 version from transformers was not having issues but even though I'm unable to use it.

Here's the full error message:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py:1382, in _LazyModule._get_module(self, module_name)
   1381 try:
-> 1382     return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.__name__)
   1383 except Exception as e:

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py:126, in import_module(name, package)
    125         level += 1
--> 126 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1206, in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1178, in _find_and_load(name, import_)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:690, in _load_unlocked(spec)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:940, in exec_module(self, module)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:241, in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/__init__.py:28
     27 from ..feature_extraction_utils import PreTrainedFeatureExtractor
---> 28 from ..image_processing_utils import BaseImageProcessor
     29 from ..models.auto.configuration_auto import AutoConfig

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/image_processing_utils.py:28
     27 from .feature_extraction_utils import BatchFeature as BaseBatchFeature
---> 28 from .image_transforms import center_crop, normalize, rescale
     29 from .image_utils import ChannelDimension

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/image_transforms.py:47
     46 if is_tf_available():
---> 47     import tensorflow as tf
     49 if is_flax_available():

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py:48
     46 _tf2.enable()
---> 48 from tensorflow._api.v2 import __internal__
     49 from tensorflow._api.v2 import __operators__

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/_api/v2/__internal__/__init__.py:8
      6 import sys as _sys
----> 8 from tensorflow._api.v2.__internal__ import autograph
      9 from tensorflow._api.v2.__internal__ import decorator

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/_api/v2/__internal__/autograph/__init__.py:8
      6 import sys as _sys
----> 8 from tensorflow.python.autograph.core.ag_ctx import control_status_ctx # line: 34
      9 from tensorflow.python.autograph.impl.api import tf_convert # line: 493

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/core/ag_ctx.py:21
     19 import threading
---> 21 from tensorflow.python.autograph.utils import ag_logging
     22 from tensorflow.python.util.tf_export import tf_export

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/utils/__init__.py:17
     15 """Utility module that contains APIs usable in the generated code."""
---> 17 from tensorflow.python.autograph.utils.context_managers import control_dependency_on_returns
     18 from tensorflow.python.autograph.utils.misc import alias_tensors

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/utils/context_managers.py:19
     17 import contextlib
---> 19 from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
     20 from tensorflow.python.ops import tensor_array_ops

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:45
     44 from tensorflow.python.client import pywrap_tf_session
---> 45 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
     46 from tensorflow.python.eager import core

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/context.py:37
     36 from tensorflow.python.eager import cancellation
---> 37 from tensorflow.python.eager import execute
     38 from tensorflow.python.eager import executor

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py:23
     22 from tensorflow.python.framework import tensor_conversion_registry
---> 23 from tensorflow.python.framework import tensor_shape
     24 from tensorflow.python.types import core as core_types

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py:26
     25 from tensorflow.python.platform import tf_logging as logging
---> 26 from tensorflow.python.saved_model import nested_structure_coder
     27 from tensorflow.python.types import trace

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/nested_structure_coder.py:38
     37 from tensorflow.python.util import compat
---> 38 from tensorflow.python.util import nest
     39 from tensorflow.python.util.compat import collections_abc

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py:93
     16 """Functions that work with structures.
     17 
     18 A structure is either:
   (...)
     90 API docstring: tensorflow.nest
     91 """
---> 93 import wrapt as _wrapt
     95 from tensorflow.python.util import _pywrap_nest

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wrapt/__init__.py:10
      4 from .wrappers import (ObjectProxy, CallableObjectProxy, FunctionWrapper,
      5         BoundFunctionWrapper, WeakFunctionProxy, PartialCallableObjectProxy,
      6         resolve_path, apply_patch, wrap_object, wrap_object_attribute,
      7         function_wrapper, wrap_function_wrapper, patch_function_wrapper,
      8         transient_function_wrapper)
---> 10 from .decorators import (adapter_factory, AdapterFactory, decorator,
     11         synchronized)
     13 from .importer import (register_post_import_hook, when_imported,
     14         notify_module_loaded, discover_post_import_hooks)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wrapt/decorators.py:34
     33 from functools import partial
---> 34 from inspect import ismethod, isclass, formatargspec
     35 from collections import namedtuple

ImportError: cannot import name 'formatargspec' from 'inspect' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/inspect.py)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 from transformers import pipeline
      3 print("Pipeline module is available!")

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1231, in _handle_fromlist(module, fromlist, import_, recursive)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py:1372, in _LazyModule.__getattr__(self, name)
   1370     value = self._get_module(name)
   1371 elif name in self._class_to_module.keys():
-> 1372     module = self._get_module(self._class_to_module[name])
   1373     value = getattr(module, name)
   1374 else:

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py:1384, in _LazyModule._get_module(self, module_name)
   1382     return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.__name__)
   1383 except Exception as e:
-> 1384     raise RuntimeError(
   1385         f"Failed to import {self.__name__}.{module_name} because of the following error (look up to see its"
   1386         f" traceback):\n{e}"
   1387     ) from e

RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.pipelines because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
cannot import name 'formatargspec' from 'inspect' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/inspect.py)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try installing the latest version of `wrapt`

```
python -m pip install wrapt==1.16.0
```